# find all the ways the a group of n pepole can be connected

Tags: algorithm, combinations

you have numbers between 1 to n. a set of number i.e. (4,5) means that person number 4 is connected to person number 5. find all the ways the a group of n pepole can be connected. i.e. for 0 and 1 there is the empty set, for 2 there is 2 ways, empty set and {1,2} only  for 3 there are 4 ways: {}, {(1,2)} {(2,3)}, {(3,1)}
for 4 there are 10 ways ({},{(1,2)}, {(1,2),(3,4)},.......

you can do it by factorial and cobination but there is another way that state that:

```
T(n)=T(n-1) + (n-1)*T(n-2)
```

(while T(n) is the function that computes the number of ways..

Can someone explain why this equation is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your question is "how many ways can we match n people into pairs" (let T(n) be this number), then you can count the options by considering the first person.

Suppose the first person is unconnected, then the number of ways is the number of ways of matching the remaining n-1 people, i.e. T(n-1).

Otherwise, the first person is connected.  There are n-1 choices for their pair, leaving n-2 people that can be connected independently.  This results in (n-1)*T(n-2) patterns where the first person is unconnected.

Putting these together we get:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + (n-1)*T(n-2)
```